# Pronunciation of 'Taxman'

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Like *Postman* /ˈpəʊstmən/, *Policeman* /pəˈliːsmən/ and *Fireman* */faɪəmən/*, one would assume that *Taxman* would also be pronounced with a schwa in the *man*. But this is not the case and it is pronounced */taksman/*. Are there any reasons for the different pronunciations of these words?

Comment: The pronunciation of "tax".

Comment: @HotLicks What about the pronunciation of 'tax' is so different from the others? I would think it is very simiiar to 'post' in 'postman' (but also I tend to pronounce it as /ˈpəʊst 'man/ if ever)

Comment: Personally I pronounce it much like *mailman* or *trashman*.

Comment: *Taxman* is always said in an ominous fashion. It's not unique though; *merman*, *frogman*, *doorman*, and many others can be pronounced either way according to Lexico, while the superheroes Batman and Spiderman are pronounced /man/.

Comment: As you can hear in the song, both syllables are stressed. That's the canonical pronunciation.

Comment: My mind has turned to scrambled egg saying these words over and over again to myself. I fail to find a significant issue. Tax, post, fire, gas etc ... all pronounced as such plus "man", with no or various slight degrees of de-emphasis on the first vowel. I also feel there are regional differences that obscure the matter.

Comment: @JohnLawler - What song?

Comment: @JohnLawler While in "postman, policeman, doorman, and fireman" the first syllable only is stressed. But in "taxman, mailman, and trashman" both get stressed. At least that's the case in the UK.  Once you introduce "woman" you stress all three in "policewoman, postwoman etc".

Comment: @JohnLawler In the U.S. we tend to stress the first syllable of "taxman". This would work in iambic meter: "The taxman is a pleasant guy." But this wouldn't: "A nice taxman is here."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan The second syllable still has secondary stress. You can tell because its vowel does not suffer the required reduction of an unstressed syllable.

Comment: @tchrist Oh, secondary stress makes sense. I misunderstood.

Comment: @HotLicks He's referring to the song "Taxman" by the Beatles. It was also covered by Stevie Ray Vaughan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John McWhorter writes about this phenomenon in his book *[Words on the Move](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Words_on_the_Move/vKqTCwAAQBAJ?hl=en)*:

> ﻿Often if a word is part of the unaccented part of [a] compound, then it starts being pronounced more fuzzily, and drifts ever farther beyond what we would think of as a word in any sense at all.
>
> Take *policeman, fireman, clergyman, postman, and gentleman*: one does not pronounce the *-man* part the way one would pronounce *man* by itself. Rather, you say something like "mun," a sludgy "whatever" kind of pronunciation. That has happened over the years, as the words have undergone
> what you could call enunciational wear. Originally, the *-man* in these words was pronounced fully, but now, if someone had no idea how English was written and heard words like *policeman* and *fireman*, they might not even associate the little *-mun* with the word *man* at all. One way we know that this pronunciation of *-man* develops gradually over time is that if you start all over again and make up a new word with *-man* on the end, you will usually pronounce the -man fully. *Anchorman* and *caveman* are newish concepts; yes, cavemen themselves date pretty far back, but what taught us that they existed was paleontology, which does not. Therefore those two words are pronounced with "man" rather than "mun."
>
> After that, chance plays its role as always: sometimes fate spares a *-man*. *Postman* is pronounced "post-mun," but there's no such thing as a "mail-mun."
>
> ---
>
> [pages 188-9]

*Taxman* isn't really a word you use every day (unless it's particularly relevant to one's life), so it means that it's not as wont to becoming sludgified. Also relevant is the fact that *taxman* is a two-syllable compound, and thus it's short enough that few people will feel the need to shorten it further. Though McWhorter's examples include a mix of shorter ones (*postman/fireman*) as well as longer ones (*clergyman/gentleman*), my accent has only worn out the longer words; I, a Midwestern, pronounce *postman* and *fireman* without a schwa. (It doesn't sound *wrong* to me to do it the other way.)

This can't be the whole story, however, and I'm sure someone else will come along and answer it fully.